# nTypeError: Can not merge type <class \'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType\'> and <class \'pyspark.sql.types.StringType\'>\n'

Tags: pandas, pyspark, databricks

I am using spark 1.6 and i am running the following code:

```
def load(self, filename):        
    print "Loading input file " + filename
    inputpd = pd.read_csv('input/'+filename , dtype=str)

    inputpd = inputpd.round(4)
    inputpd = inputpd.drop(inputpd.columns[[0]], axis=1)
    df_input = self.sqlContext.createDataFrame(inputpd)
    return df_input
```

After running the code I am getting the type error:

> `Can not merge type <class \'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType\'> and <class \'pyspark.sql.types.StringType\'>\n'`

To resolve this I have already tried:

```
inputpd = (spark.read.format("csv").options(header="true").load('input/'+filename))
```

and also:

```
inputpd = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('input/'+filename)
```

But both the times I have gotten error spark or sqlcontext not defined. Please let me know how I can define because I have already tried import statement.

Comment: I have resolved the issue but now i am getting the error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv                                                                                            how to resolve this using spark submit command?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with pyspark and works...

```
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0
```

See [this one](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#using-with-spark-shell).

```
sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load("file:/home/..." + filename).collect()
```